# F3 Fat Free Framework DB::() works on one database, but not the other (same host)

Tags: fat-free-framework

Just had some code developed on the F3 framework, which I'm not very familiar with. Essentially, the index page contains one database connection as such:

F3::set('DB',
    new DB(
        'mysql:host=71.123.123.32;port=3306;dbname=DBNAME',
        'DBUSERNAME',
        'DBPASSWORD'
    )
);

This was developed using a dev database on the same host. We are now switching to the live db, and suddenly we are receiving server errors and max php memory limit warnings. Has anyone had this happen to them before? We are confused, and the developer is pretty stumped as well. He has used the typical F3 setup, nothing additional. Thanks in advance for any comments/suggestions...

Comment: If you just change the DB connection itself, nothing special should happen. Set the DEBUG to 2 or 3 and check the error message. also check the error_log of your server.

Comment: is your table schema correct on the live server?